# Apply the Implicit Function Theorem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

I'm trying to find $dz$ and $d^2z$ for the function defined by the equation $F(\frac{x}{z},\frac{y}{z}) = k$, where $F \in C^2$.

To solve the problem, the most natural way to proceed in my mind is to apply the Implicit Function Theorem to find $z(x,y)$ around $z \in \mathbb{R}, z \neq 0$ and then compute the total differentials.

If that's correct, my next question is how I should obtain $z(x,y)$. I don't know how to think about the arguments of $F$ being expressed in terms $z$. Is a change of variables necessary?

If that's incorrect, what is the best strategy here?

Thank you.

Comment: You can think of your equation as being of the form $G(x,y,z)=k$ where $G$ is the composition $F\circ f$ of $F$ and the mapping $f:\Bbb{R}^3\to\Bbb{R}^2, (x,y,z)\mapsto (x/z,y/z)$. Use the chain rule to write down the partial derivatives of $G$ in terms of partial derivatives of $F$ and $f$, and then use IFT normally.

Comment: In other words, think of $F$ as $F(u,v)$ with $u=f_1(x,y,z)=x/z$ and $v=f_2(x,y,z)=y/z$.